# Is is possible to decrease connection that made to db?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm

Currently, my Django application has millions of records and I want to update based on it's `ManyToMany` related fields value.

Consequently what I did works, but it took so many times. In order to update only three records, it uses ***13*** queries.

`Record` model has `genres` field which is `ManyToMany` field. Also, has `authors` field which is also `ManyToMany` field.

And lastly, `Author` model has `ManyToMany` field that implies `genres`.

```
for i in Record.objects.filter(authors__popular=True).only("authors", "genres"): 
    for a in i.authors.all(): 
        print(a.name)  # test purpose
        for genre in i.genres.all(): 
            if a.genres.exists(): 
                a.genres.add(genre)
```

When i run `len(connection.queries)` it shows query numbers that ran, i want it to be lesser than 13.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So far i just decreased query number to 1 for 1 record. This is how i achieved

```
for i in Author.objects.annotate(record_count=Count('record'), record_genres=ArrayAgg('record__genres', distinct=True):
    if i.record_count > 0 and i.record_genres:
        i.genres.set(i.record_genres)
        i.save()
```